# Get the route group name of a route

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I'am creating a job on laravel 5.6 that will run only when the route are not inside the route group named `administrator` so i have many routes like

```
Route::get('foo','Controller');
Route::get('bar','Controller');
Route::name('administrator')->group(function(){
    Route::get('baz','Controller');
    ....
});
```

How can I get the group name if I'm inside `baz` route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```php
Request::route()->getName();
```

This will return `administrator` in your case because you've declared the route group as given below:

```php
Route::name('administrator')->group(function(){
    Route::get('baz','Controller');
});
```

Also, if your route inside a group has it's own name for example:

```php
Route::name('administrator.')->group(function(){
    Route::name('foo')->get('baz', function() {
        dd(Request::route()->getName());
    });
});
```

You'll get `administrator.foo`.